# How to get target item details on which source item dropped ( ng2-dragula / angular )

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-dragula

Problem: I would require a way to implement following using the [ng2-dragula](https://valor-software.com/ng2-dragula/index.html) drop behaviour.

- I am trying to build something that resembles the app-launcher on iOS
  & Android devices.
- I want to drag an **item A** and drop it on-top of another existing **item
  B.**
- When I place it on top of another **item B**, I want to react on this by
  creating a folder item containing both items (which would be
  functionality I would implement in angular/typescript logic).

> In current ng2-dragula library, when I drag **item A** & drop on
>   **item B** it gives me details of **item A** as el in onDrop event, however it does not tell how to find **item B**.

I am struggling to figure out, how to find **item B**. Means, how to figure out on which element **item A** was dropped?

> Demo : I have created a demo plunker to show dragula setup & an
>   exercise.

```
private onDrop(args) {
    let [el, target, source] = args;
    // do something else
        console.log(`ondrop element: ${el.innerText.trim()}`);
        console.log(`ondrop target container: ${target.innerText.trim()}`);
        console.log(`ondrop source container: ${source.innerText.trim()}`);

  }

  private onDrag(args) {
    let [el, source] = args;
    // do something else
        console.log(`ondrag element: ${el.innerText.trim()}`);
        console.log(`ondrag source container: ${source.innerText.trim()}`);
  }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/xXFWfS0Ae8fts2UL94mo

I tried attaching a mouseover event on elements, and later find it inside dragula onDrop event but it does not capture element B detail ( or whichever item A was dropped on).

Can you please suggest how can I solve this?

Thanks a lot for your guidance!

Comment: I made a fork of ng2-dragula that emits a tuple for onDrop that includes the model array of the dropped-on bag; maybe this would be helpful for you? It's a few commits behind master at this point: https://github.com/spongessuck/ng2-dragula

Comment: @spongessuck: Thanks for your feedback, so that means this feature yet not available in stable release of ng2-dragula? Anyways I wasted a day figuring this out & ended up using ng2-dnd ( https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd ) as its more configurable and trigger standard javascript event dragstart / dragend / drag on a element, I could not do same in case of ng2-dragula.

Comment: That's correct; it has not been merged at this point. ng2-dnd looks interesting. Maybe answer your own question at this point to say you went with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful, but when you subscribe the value when drag and drop and put it in ngOnInit, the data after performing the action will be shown when console.log. Something like this:

**Component**

```
function(){
 this.service.drag.subscribe(value => {console.log(value)});
 this.service.drop.subscribe(value => {console.log(value)});
}
ngOnInit(){
 this.function();
}
```